# Using shell expansion with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to execute a remote command via Ansible which requires gathering the PID of the process:

```
ansible webserver -m shell -a 'jstack -l $(pgrep -f java)'
```

However it seems Ansible is not able to expand the shell command contained in parenthesis (tried as well with grave accent):

```
127.0.0.1 | FAILED | rc=1 >>
Usage:
    jstack [-l] <pid>
```

Executing just the command in the expansion reveals that expansion does not take place:

```
ansible webserver  -a 'echo $(pgrep -f java)'
192.168.0.1 | success | rc=0 >>
$(pgrep -f java)
```

Comment: `ansible webserver  -a 'echo $(pgrep -f java)'` calls `command` module (default) – which doesn't expand shell thing, while `ansible webserver -m shell -a 'echo $(pgrep -f java)'` calls `shell` module, which does. Please try again with `shell` module.

Comment: Something wacky is going on- what version of Ansible, what's the controller OS and the target OS and shell on the target OS? Your command works as expected for me on ansible devel...

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to escape the `$` dollar sign, like so:

`ansible all -i inventories/prod/hosts -m shell -a "echo \$(pgrep -f java)"`

Comment: OP uses single quotes `'`, so escaping is not required!

Comment: Ah, obviously. My bad